# Version agnostic PHP-FPM restart

Tags: php, reboot, versions, php7, php-fpm

This is how I restart PHP-FPM in Debian oriented systems:

```
/etc/init.d/php7.0-fpm restart
```

Is there a version agnostic way? All ways I tried [from here](https://serverfault.com/questions/189940/how-do-you-restart-php-fpm) (besides the one above), failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the Bash star(`*`) wildcard, as referenced in the Bash manpage:

> * Matches any string, including the null string. When the globstar shell option is enabled, and * is used in a pathname expansion context, two adjacent *s used as a single pattern will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories. If followed by a /, two adjacent *s will match only directories and subdirectories.

In your case:

```
/etc/init.d/php*-fpm restart
```

or perhaps

```
/etc/init.d/php*-fpm* restart
```

to account for the version number being after the `fpm`.

Comment: This doesn't work Usage: /etc/init.d/php-fpm5.6 {start|stop|status|restart|reload|force-reload}